# Qt: display dynamically composed non-English text on Labels or buttons

Tags: qt, translation, hindi, qpushbutton

I am trying to display some dynamically generated hindi text on a QPushbutton.

Please have a look at the following code:

```
char nam[] = { 40, 9, 62, 9, 46, 9 };
QString nameStringInHindi(QString::fromRawData((QChar *)nam, 3));
qDebug() << nameStringInHindi;
```

Output:
"नाम"

But if I do
    ui->pushButton->setText(nameStringInHindi) //some junk characters are getting printed.

I have tried setting up the application font as well.

```
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/usr/share/fonts/lohit-devanagari/Lohit-Devanagari.ttf")
```

and 
    QApplication::setFont(QFont("Lohit Devanagari",12));

but it did not help.

Could someone please help me with this issue?
Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know *why* your code doesn't work, but adding an empty string to the string created from raw data somehow fixes the string. This works in Linux with Qt 5.0.1:

```
QString nameStringInHindi(QString::fromRawData((QChar*)nam, 3) + "");
```

Comment: Thanks Roku. Adding an empty string makes it work even with Qt 4.7.4 and 4.8.4. It would be great if somebody could explain how this solves the problem. Is it a bug?